# Get HTTP Header Values

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to get HTTP Header Values from a specific Header File (i do not know what they are called).
With Header Files i mean this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjfJz.jpg.
How can i read the Status Code from that?   I tried to get this Code but it returned me OK(200) while the username didn't even exists

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https//tiktok.com/@euiwfhnneuwih");

            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into [```HttpClient.GetAsync```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-5.0). You can use the [```IsSuccessStatusCode```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=net-5.0) property on the returned ```HttpResponseMessage```.

Comment: Open the file with notepad and read the headers. An html file has a header and body.  When you connect to the URL you are downloading the html file.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what do you want to do. Could you explain please?
Just call ```content.StatusCode```` to get the status code value, if this is your purpose

Comment: "i do not know what they are called"...they're called HTTP Headers. They're contained in the response to your HTTP request, along with the body. Ignore jdweng's comment, they thought you were talking about the HTML header element, but its clear you're not. The other two comments are relevant though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know what the headers are you can just run your code through the debugger and look at the values from the example I have provide here.  Once you see what the headers are called you can then retrieve them in your code like I am doing down below.  You can also just get the status code from response.

You can set and get default headers from the client itself like so

```
    var client = new HttpClient(); 

    // Set headers like this
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/*+xml;version=5.1");

    // this gives you the string value of the header
    var requestHeader = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ToString(); 
    // this gives you an IEnumerable<string> of headers
    var requestHeader2 = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.GetValues("Accept");

    // You can retrieve the header like this.
    var acceptHeader = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ToString();
```

To get them you would do the same thing, but get them from response.Header.

```
    var response = client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result;
    var cacheControlHeader = response.Headers.CacheControl.ToString();
    var cacheControlHeader2 = response.Headers.GetValues("Cache-Control");

    // The status code can be retrieved like this
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
```

Comment: As seen in the picture, i want to get the headers out of that File.